# Is Akka Ask Blocking on the Current Thread

Tags: scala, akka

I have a scenario where I have to fetch the details of a user by his id. It is a HTTP request that comes in and in my HTTP handler layer, I make use of the id that I get from the request, send a message to the actor which then talks to the database service to fetch the user.

Now since this is a HTTP request, I need to satisfy the request by sending a response back. So I thought of using the Akka ask pattern, but I have the following questions in mind:

1. Is this going to block on my current thread?
2. Is using ask pattern here to fetch a user in my case a scalable solution? I mean, I could have a few hundreds to a million users calling this end point at any given point in time. Is this a good idea to use the ask pattern to fetch a user?

In code, it looks like this in my HTTP controller

```
val result: Future[Any] = userActor ? FetchUser(id)
```

In my actor, I would do the following:

```
case fetchUser: FetchUser => sender ! myService.getUser(fetchUser.id)
```

Comment: How are you returning your response? Are you using a future response?

Comment: In my actor, I just do a sender ! User

Comment: I am assuming the flow to be something like, get a HTTP request, use ask pattern to return some result and await on result from actor and give response. Is that so?

Comment: What do you mean by awaiting on result from the actor? In my actor, I do the following: sender ! dbService.fetchUser(userId), where the fetchUser(....) method in dbService is returning a Future result!

Comment: Ok, does the framework/application server you are using allows you to send a Future response?

Comment: I'm using Spray, so a Future response should be possible!

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear with my post! My question was, if I use the Akka ask pattern on my HTTP controller, am I blocking some threads in my controller? In other words, is akka ask pattern scalable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions in the same order you posed them:

1. No, using the `?` does not block the current thread.  It returns a `Future` immediately.  However, the result within the Future may not be available immediately.
2. If you need the solution to be "scalable", and your service is capable of multiple concurrent queries, then you may need to use a [pool](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/routing.html#Pool) of Actors so you can serve multiple `?` at once, or see below for a Futures only, scalable, solution.

**Futures Exclusively**

If your Actors are not caching any intermediate values then you can just use Futures directly and avoid the rigmarole of Actors (e.g. Props, actorOf, receive, ?, ...):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext,Future}    

object ServicePool {      

  private val myService = ???

  val maxQueries = 11 //should come from a configuration file instead

  private val queryExecutionPool = 
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxQueries))

  type ID = ???

  /**Will only hit the DB with maxQueries at once.*/
  def queryService(id : ID) = 
    Future { myService getUser id }(queryExecutionPool)

}//end object ServiceQuery
```

You can now call `ServicePool.queryService` as often as you want but the service will not be hit with more than `maxQueries` at a single time, and no Actors:

```
val alotOfIDs : Seq[ID] = (1 to 1000000) map { i => ID(i)}

val results = alotOfIDs map ServicePool.queryService
```

Comment: Yes, I have a Actor pool, so I do not see an issue there!