# The blocking in the ask pattern of akka actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am learning about Slick and I found this example `Akka Http` + `Slick` in `Github` here: https://github.com/adekunleba/sample-slick.

When looking at the code I see `Akka Actors` in the class `UserRegistryActor` (https://github.com/adekunleba/sample-slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/exampleslick/UserRegistryActor.scala).

So let's say the service is running:

- using a curl I create a `request` (`POST`)
- `Akka http` process the `request` in `UserRoutes` class
- Then use `?` (ask pattern) for creating the user:

```scala
val userCreated = (userRegistryActor ? CreateUser(user)).mapTo[ActionPerformed]
```

- So the thread is blocked until the user has been created or timeout.
- Then if the creation is ok it will return status `Created`.

My question is what's the benefit of using actors with `?` ?
The `Slick` methods returns `Futures` so I can call them in the `route` class or also I can create a new service layer (a new class) ...
I don't understand why this example is using `Actors`, what's the benefit ...

Comment: Does [Is Akka Ask Blocking on the Current Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623492/is-akka-ask-blocking-on-the-current-thread) answer your question?

Comment: In addition to what is mentioned there, the mailbox of an actor always gets processed sequentially. Using a `Future` would not guarantee the same ordering, if that matters for the business logic. For further reference on the blocking operations for Akka, please take a look at [Dispatchers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html#dispatchers) and [handling blocking operations](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html)

Comment: The right way to do this is to use the `pipeToSelf` pattern inside the blocking actor, which in this case accesses the database, as officially documented in [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#send-future-result-to-self)

Comment: @James It's technically OK, since no actor state is closed over (and you might want to edit the link to point to the classic docs)

Comment: @LeviRamsey Thanks for the feedback. Yet, I don’t get it. What do you mean by “no actor state is closed over.” And isn’t using typed actors, as the newest technology, always better? I haven’t worked with the classics, so if you can provide the link, it would be nice.

Comment: The benefit of using actors is that your Akka-http thread would be free to process other requests for other users while it is waiting for the Slick actor to send the result back.

Comment: @James The reason `pipeTo` is advised is because it's really easy to refer to the actor's state (`sender` in Classic being probably the most prominent example).  If the future callback doesn't refer to the actor's state.  I only suggested linking to the classic docs because the code in question is using classic.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Yes, in addition, it is mentioned that using `pipeTo` is safer for accessing the actor’s state than `onComplete`